# Using std::vector Copy Constructor In a Message

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I am attempting the following code:

```
vector<float> ranges(360, 10); //A vector of 360 '10's
sensor_msgs::LaserScan currentScan;
currentScan.ranges(ranges);   // <---------- Fails
```

Here is the cryptic error message:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >) (std::vector<float,std::allocator<float> >&)’
```

I tried googling similar errors but to no avail.  If someone could offer some readings on the failure behind this, I would really appreciate this.  Thank you

Constantin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11674/using-std::vector-copy-constructor-in-a-message/) by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 296 on 2011-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't use copy-constructor syntax because currentScan.ranges has already been constructed (as part of the constructor for `sensor_msgs::LaserScan`).

Assignment will work, though:

```
currentScan.ranges = ranges;
```

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on 2011-10-25**:
Ahh of course.  Thank you!